# New Column Value Based on Highest Value in a Series of Other Columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL that looks like the one below. I have created a new `Text` column called  `Most_Popular_Mode`. The existing columns are all `INT8`. Each existing column contains some zero values. I want to populate the new column `Most_Popular_Mode` with a single word based on which column contains the highest value. If they are all 0 I need to populate `No_Relevant_Value`. Can I use a combination of `CASE` and `GREATEST`?

I'm using PostgreSQL 13.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit.

| One_Method_Car | One_Method_Bus | One_Method_Train | One_Method_Ferry | Most_Popular_Mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 5 | 3 | Train |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | No_Relevant_Value |
| 5 | 8 | 7 | 1 | Bus |

Comment: What happens if they're all the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a correlated subquery, unpivoting each column into a separate row and selecting the top value sorted by number.

```sql
SELECT *,
  COALESCE((
    SELECT type
    FROM (VALUES
      (t.One_Method_Car, 'Car'),
      (t.One_Method_Bus, 'Bus'),
      (t.One_Method_Train, 'Train'),
      (t.One_Method_Ferry, 'Ferry')
    ) v(num, type)
    WHERE num <> 0
    ORDER BY num DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ), 'No_Relevant_Value')
FROM YourTable t;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/A7oL4I_b)